# What method should I use for a sidebar widget that reads latest posts?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, widgets, sidebar

At the moment, I'm building a website for a local NGO and I have the following situation: in the sidebar, I should have a widget that displays the title of the latest editorials from the members of the NGO. These editorials are published on external sites. So, my widget will look something like this:

first row: Post title (The title of the editorial with a link to the external site)
second row: Author Name (The name of the editorial's author [plain text]) | Website (the name of the website that hosts the editorial [plain text])
My dilemma is how to built this widget.

Here are my thoughts:

a) I should build a custom post type with custom taxonomies. The tag should be the Author Name and the Category the website. And the solution would be to build a widget that reads the latest posts from the custom post type and below displays the tag and category (without links on them [is that possible???])

b) I should build a custom post type and two custom fields. Then I should build the widget that reads the latest posts from the custom post type and below displays the two custom fields.

Which road should I go? Do you have another ideea on how this can be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need custom post types? Using the external feeds is probably easier.

Comment: And so on that note, the answer most likely is XML, provided it is available. Is it? I'm a fan of SimpleXML myself: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I thought using XML but the problem is that these guys are publishing editorials on a lot of websites around the globe. There are websites where they publish an editorial/month and websites where they publish editorials/2years. Besides that, some of the websites don't have feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't need the querying power taxonomies will offer, but it would make sense to use if you think you'll frequently have the same authors publishing; reduces redundant data (i.e. lots of the same entries in post meta) and improves the UX for administrators.

Same applies for websites; if there'll be many with rarely ever the same, stick with meta.

Either way, a custom post type seems like a good plan to me.

Comment: Thanks TheDeadMedic. I will stick with the meta because they will always have the same authors and the websites in 70% of the cases will be the same.

Besides that, I need to make it really easy for the administrators.

Comment: If they'll (almost) always be the same, go with taxonomies! Sorry if my wording caused some confusion there.

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you completely....but  use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/ then get the feeds and customize it to your widget.... also this plugin will give you the excerpt of the external post..... and will link it to the external post.....

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my above comment on why I can't use feeds.